# Where do I install anaconda if my username has spaces in it? (windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, python, anaconda

I am trying to install anaconda but it says I can't install it on a path that has spaces and my user name is "[first name] [last name]." I tried make a new folder called anaconda under "users" but then windows tells me that the path is not writable... Where do I install anaconda?

Comment: `c:\apps\anaconda` should work. You might have to fiddle with permissions.

Comment: @DavidPostill Ok thanks, Ill try that. Before I do though, what if I run the installer as administrator? Would that work?/Is that a bad idea? Edit: actually it turns out I don't even have a c:\apps

Comment: You can create `C:\apps` if the folder does not exist.